# How to run a hello word Vapor app in minikube? How to set up hashicorps in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, hashicorp-vault, vapor

I am new to Kubernetes. Did this so far:

```
vapor new hello -n
open Package.swift
ls
cd hello
open Package.swift
swift run
docker compose build
docker image ls
docker compose up app
minikube kubectl -- apply -f docker-compose.yml
minikube kubectl -- apply -f docker-compose.yml --validate=false
```

based on this tutorial: https://docs.vapor.codes/deploy/docker/
and video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFhzu7LolUU

but I got following error in two last line:

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro hello % minikube kubectl -- apply -f docker-compose.yml 
error: error validating "docker-compose.yml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Someone said, I need to set up a deployment file?! https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment

My second goal is I would have hashicorp install in the cluster to be able to return short living secrets. I.e. secret for connection to a database which is used by the cluster. Would you give a step by step tutorial how can I do it?

// docker-compose.yml

```
x-shared_environment: &shared_environment
  LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL:-debug}
  
services:
  app:
    image: hello:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    # user: '0' # uncomment to run as root for testing purposes even though Dockerfile defines 'vapor' user.
    command: ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

Comment: when you try to apply a basic kubernetes file afaik it must be having few important things like apiversion,Kind,Metadata and spec. Can you share what is exactly present inside the yaml file ?

Comment: I shared it....

Comment: That's a Docker Compose YAML file, which can only be used with the Compose tool (and absent a `version:` line, only very current versions of it).  You can't feed it directly to `kubectl`.

Comment: This is a docker-compose.yaml file no wonder you were getting error while applying the file.  cab you refer this link you might need to use something like a deployment.yml and then apply it. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in simple words when you try to apply a file in Kubernetes you will need to follow a basic template which make Kubernetes understand what kind of resource you are trying to create. One of this is apiVersion so please try to follow the below deployment I was not able to find the docker image for the application here you will need to just add the docker image and port number where the application runs.

If you have the Dockerfile you can build and push the image to container registry and then use the image tag to pull the same image.

Reference : [How to write Kubernetes manifest file](https://eskala.io/tutorial/how-to-write-yaml-files-for-kubernetes/)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vaporapp
  labels:
    app: vaporapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vaporapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vaporapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vaporapp
        image: signalsciences/example-helloworld:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vapor-service
  labels:
    app: vaporapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: vaporapp
  type: LoadBalancer
```